# Need rowid from a query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get the rowid from a query. My query is :

> Table: test ( PersonId number, AssetId number);

Query:

```
with abc as(
select      
       personid , 
       row_number() over(partition by personid order by personid,carid) rnk       
from test
--group by personid,carid,rowid
)
select rowid, abc.* from abc ;
```

and its throwing error.

```
ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from,or sample,a view with DISTINCT,GROUP BY etc
```

Is there any way i can get the rowid (this way) or its not allowed to get rowid using the way am trying to get in Oracle. Can anyone throw some views here. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Why do you think you need the ROWID? And why do you have the `group by` if you are not aggregating in the inner query?

Comment: You can see why i needed that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404842/delete-rows-to-have-maximum-x-lines-per-group-in-oracle-table/39410327#39410327

Comment: Well the `group by` in that answer is totally useless.

Comment: It makes sense where i used it..Check out.

Comment: No, it does not make sense. `group by rowid` will create one group for each row in the result - effectively not grouping at all. And in the context of that answer, the group by is simply wrong (even without the rowid)

Comment: But it achieves absolutely nothing. `group by rowid` will return **exactly** the same result as not grouping at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including rowid inside the with subquery ( I used an alias)

```
with abc as(
select      
       personid , 
       rowid as r, 
       row_number() over(partition by personid order by personid,carid) rnk       
from test
/***This was unwanted in question***/
--group by personid,carid,rowid
)
select r, personid, rnk 
 from abc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY` with `ROWID` will not aggregate rows as `ROWID` is unique so the size of each group will always be 1.

You can just do:

```
SELECT personid,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY carid ) AS rnk,
       ROWID
FROM   test;
```